# Find the dimension and basis of $U = \{ (x,y,z,w,t) : x+y+z+w+t=0 \, \mathrm{and} \, x-y+z-w+t=0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have no idea how to go about this question but from the site's I have visited I have managed to understand that the question has 3 dimensions.

Help me answer this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

From the secon equation we get $ y= x+z-w+t$, which leads to (substituting back into the first) $x + (x+z-w+t) + z + w + t = 0$ or, in other words $2x + 2z + 2t = 0$.

If $char(\mathbb{K}) \ne 2$ we have $x = -z - t$ we give us

(Char denotes the [Characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra)))

$$ U = \left\lbrace (x,y,z,t) :  \begin{cases} y = -w \\ x = -z - t\end{cases} \right\rbrace $$

Which substituting leads to

$$Span_{\mathbb{K}}(\begin{pmatrix}-1\\ 0 \\1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}-1\\ 0 \\0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\ -1 \\0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix})$$

Which are linearly independant (can you find an invertibille 3x3 minor in the completed matrix ?), So the dimension of the span is $3$.

Can you see what happens if $char(\mathbb{K}) = 2$ ?